# Deno.run has not message output in terminal?

Tags: deno

in windows

the following code has ouput message in terminal

```js
const p = Deno.run({
    cmd: ['git', 'config', '-l'],
    stdout: 'piped'
})

console.log(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(await p.output()))
```

but this following code has not ouput message in terminal

```js
const p = Deno.run({
    cmd: ['git', 'config', '-l'],
    stdout: 'inherit',
    stderr: 'inherit
})
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.run):

> "inherit" The default if unspecified. The child inherits from the corresponding parent descriptor.

i.e. if you want the output you should use `"piped"`.